# bottom margin is not working on html page

Tags: css, html, margin

Div with class 'post-subtitle' should have a bottom margin 50px but, it's not displayed/visible on page. It's definition is following:

```
.post-subtitle{  margin: 50 0 50; }
```

Why all others margins work cerrectly but bottom one for this div?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/991c7so8/4/)

HTML Code:

```
 <section >
        <div class='post'>
          <div class='post-title'> Title fo post 1</div>
          <div class='post-subtitle'>
            <div class='added-by'>BY <SPAN class='blue'>MARK XXXX</SPAN></div>
            <div class='added-at'>10:10:00 12/12/2014</div>
          </div>
          <div class='post-body'>

            <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body 
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body 
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body </p>        
          </div>      
        </div>      
        <div class='post'>
          <div class='post-title'> Title fo post 1</div>
          <div class='post-subtitle'>
            <div class='added-by'>BY <SPAN class='blue'>MARK XXXX</SPAN></div>
            <div class='added-at'>10:10:00 12/12/2014</div>
          </div>
          <div class='post-body'>
            <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body 
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body </p>
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body
            Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body
          </div>      
          <div class='post-read-more blue'>Read More ...</div>          
          <div class='post-share-it'>
            <img src="images/social-facebook.png" class="share-it">
            <img src="images/social-twitter.png" class="share-it">
            <img src="images/social-google.png" class="share-it">
            <img src="images/social-linkedin.png" class="share-it">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='post'>
          <div class='post-title'> Testing icons</div>
          <div class='post-subtitle'>
            <div class='added-by'>BY <SPAN class='blue'>MARK XXXX</SPAN></div>
            <div class='added-at'>10:10:00 12/12/2014</div>
          </div>
          <div class='post-body'>
            <i class="fa-rss">AAAA</i> 
            <i class="fa-rss-square">BBBB</i> 
          </div>      
        </div>                                 
      </section>
```

CSS code:

```
 .post-read-more{    
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;  
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
  }

  .post-share-it{
    margin: 10px 0px 30px;
  }

  .added-by {
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .added-at {
    float: right;      
    font-size: 10px;
  }

.post-title {
  /*  padding: 0 10px;  */
  font-family: "source-serif-pro",Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
  font-size: 30px;   
}

  .post-subtitle{
    margin: 50 0 50;    
  }

  .post-body{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: auto;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;  
    font-size: 10px;  
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.share-it
{
  /* width: 24%; */
}

.subsection-title{  
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;  
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;  
}

/* input test formating */
.form-group{
  margin: 5px 0px 15px;
}

.form-control{
  font-size: 12px; 
  height: 25px;
}

.input-group-addon{
  font-size: 12px; 
  background: blue;
  padding: 3 3;
}


section{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  /*  display: block;  */
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Comment: You miss the `px` in `.post-subtitle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your css  :-

```
.post-subtitle:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/991c7so8/12/)

and as the comment  add px after 50.

Answer (score 0):

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/991c7so8/5/)

```
 .post-subtitle{
    margin: 50px 0 50px;
    /*  width: auto;  */
  }
```

Comment: Nothing changed in FF, still no bottom margin.

Comment: Please explain how this code provides a solution to the question. This will help the OP and future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-subtitle {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working once you add the px, I leave an updated jsfiddle

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/991c7so8/10/)

```
.post-subtitle{  margin: 50px 0 50px 0; }
```

However, if you want to add spaces you shouldn't do it in the margin of an element, you should do it in it's padding, as it's better to control later on when you work with more elements on the page, so I recommend this code and it will give you better results,

```
.post-subtitle{ margin: 0px; padding: 50px 0 50px 0; }
```

Cheers